# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}$ converge by basics test (comparison, integral, ratio, root)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have problem to prove that this series is converge. I know that it's converge without any proof but don't know how to prove it. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}$$

Comment: $$0\leqslant\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}\leqslant\frac{4^n+4^n}{0+6^n}=2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n}{6^n}=\frac56\cdot\frac1{1-\frac56}=5$$

since
$$4^n+n<(4+1)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

For instance:
$$
\left(\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}\right)^{1/n} \to \frac 46 \in (-1,1)
$$

Comment: The root test will work like that if $a_n = \frac{4^n}{6^n}$ but here it's a little different so I can't use the root test

Comment: of course you can. why not?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see addition of a strong term plus a weak term, I consider the limit comparison test.  Here, we have strong plus weak in both the numerator and the denominator.  Choose the new sequence to be the fraction with only the strong parts included: $\frac{4^n}{6^n}$.  Read up on the limit comparison test if you're not sure how to proceed.